# Indefinite integrals with Wolfram Alpha - my test cases fail sometimes - why?

Tags: indefinite-integrals, wolfram-alpha

I'd like to learn to use Wolfram Alpha to find indefinite integrals, but I'm not getting expected results for even simple test cases. I must be doing something wrong but I don't know what.

`integrate exp(-a(y^2+x^2)) dx` and `integrate exp(-a(1+x^2)) dx` fail:

> [image]
>
> [image]

but `integrate exp(-ay^2)exp(-ax^2) dx` and `integrate exp(-a)exp(-ax^2) dx` give me apparently correct answers:

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: This is perhaps more appropriate on the Mathematica SE.

Comment: @Lovsovs actually Wolfram Alpha Website questions seem to be off-topic there. If I look at  the tag `wolfram-alpha-queries× 105` it says:
"Use this for questions about calling Wolfram Alpha from Mathematica. Questions about Wolfram Alpha itself are off-topic." I assume the last part means off-topic on the site, not off-topic for the tag only.

Comment: @Lovsovs I double checked - the Wolfram Alpha website is [explicitly off-topic there](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "*Some kinds of questions are considered off-topic: Questions on Wolfram Alpha (but questions on using Wolfram Alpha within Mathematica are okay) [...]*."

Comment: @uhoh Huh, didn't realize that, good catch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because WA interprets `a` as a function in the failed examples, not a constant. Who knows why. (I found this by requesting the Mathematica input form from within Mathematica.)

Just put a `*` sign after the `a` to fix it.

Comment: Great, thank you! Your method also works on line - there is an *Open code* button, wrong: `Integrate[Exp[-a[1 + x^2]], x]`  right: `Integrate[Exp[-(a (1 + x^2))], x]` Thanks!